# jQuery: Check if both input field values are > 0

Tags: jquery, validation, input

since I started with jQuery a few weeks ago, I still need some support with a few things..

I have to input fields (type=number). If both input field values are filled out (both, not just one), and if they are bigger than 0. A hidden element should be displayed.

I came up with this.. but I think I don't understand the each loop...

This is my code so far.. Thanks in advance!

```js
$('#container').on('input', '.sides', function(){ 
    $.each($('input[type=number]'),function(){
     if(this.value > 0){
       $('#content').removeClass('hidden');
      } else {
       $(this).addClass('marker');
      }
    });   
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display:none;
}
.marker {
  border:3px solid red;
  background:yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
<input type="number" class="sides" id="side_a">
<input type="number" class="sides" id="side_b">

<div class="hidden" id="content">
<h1>
Hello :)
</h1>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `filter` to get a list of `inputs` that match your condition - then compare to the total length:

```
var hasFilledInEverything = $('input[type=number]').filter(function() {
    return this.value > 0;
}).length == $('input[type=number]').length;

if (hasFillerInEverything) {
    //add class
} else {
    //remove
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This filter function comes in very handy :)

Answer (score 1):

An `$.each()` call is not required here, you just need to get the value of both `input` elements within the `input` event and compare them. Try this:

```js
$('#container').on('input', '.sides', function() {
  var aValue = $('#side_a').val();
  var bValue = $('#side_b').val();
  if (aValue > 0 && bValue > 0) {
    $('#content').removeClass('hidden');
  } else {
    $('#content').addClass('hidden');
    $(this).addClass('marker');
  }
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
.marker {
  border: 3px solid red;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <input type="number" class="sides" id="side_a">
  <input type="number" class="sides" id="side_b">

  <div class="hidden" id="content">
    <h1>
Hello :)
</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I know, but this code is just a prototype for a big form. So I want to validate every input field with the same class with the same condition.

Comment: In which case the solution posted by @tymeJV is a better fit for your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Each is just like a for loop.
So that code equals:

```
for( i = 0; i < $('input[type=number]').length; i++{
  if($('input[type=number]')[i] > 0){
    $('#content').removeClass('hidden');
  } else {
    $('input[type=number]')[i].addClass('marker');
  }
}
```

Basically, you are not taking in consideration both inputs in that code. If you are to use $each, you'll need an auxiliary variable to track your results, and after the loop act based on it

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I was not aware of that.. :)